# Use the bang-commands (e.g. '!!') of bash in scripts and aliases?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc, bash-history

Is it possible to use the so-called bang-commands (`!` + command/symbol, like e.g. `!!` or `!$:p`) in bash scripts and in bash aliases?

I wanted to add the line

```
alias getit='sudo apt-get install !!'
```

to my `~/.bashrc` file to be able to install a not found command by typing `getit` after the non-successful call to the command itself, similar to the behavior of the tool [The Fuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck), just with less swearing...

However, this line does not work as can be seen in the output below:

```
$ cowsay
The application »cowsay« is currently not installed.
You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install cowsay

$ getit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package !!

$
```

Note that I translated the output of the first command myself from German, as `LANG=C` did not work on that... For whatever reason.

Anyway, you can see that the bang-command in the alias does not get interpreted to be replaced with the last executed command but stays the same string. I already found out that bang-commands usually only work within the interactive shell and therefore not within scripts.

Can this setting be changed, so that `!!` gets interpreted as the last executed command string within scripts? How about aliases, is it possible there?

Comment: It's not possible in aliases, I tried myself before with no success

Comment: @Maythux What about scripts? Or might there eventually be a workaround to achieve the same functionality as `!!` without bang-commands but regular commands?

Comment: I really have same question of you in mind, I don't really know what is the matter for that I just answered you for what I've faced before

Comment: Just a couple of comments on your use-case: (1) you can't rely on the name of the package being the same as the command and (2) at a minimum you'd probably want `!:0` rather than `!!` in case your original command included arguments.

Comment: Indeed, I think there was a recent question about getting the command not going program doing the installation as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

History expansion is done before alias expansion, so you'll have to use the `history` built-in to perform the expansion yourself:

```
alias getit='sudo apt-get install $(history -p !!)'
```

---

However, the above alias uses the whole last executed command as argument for `sudo apt-get install`, which means if we had given an argument to the failed command (like `cowsay "Hello"`), we would now also have this argument appearing in the list of packages to install (`sudo apt-get install cowsay "Hello"`).

As this is not intended, we should modify the alias as *steeldriver* suggested and use `!:0` instead of `!!` to only get the first word (the command name):

```
alias getit='sudo apt-get install $(history -p !:0)'
```

We still have to take care that this procedure only works, if the failed  command name and its package name are equal. It would e.g. not work for the command `lynx` (a CLI browser), because it is included in the package `lynx-cur`.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Would you please add steeldriver's comment to your answer and provide the alternative with `$(history -p !:0)` to only return the first word of the command, so that arguments are left out?

Comment: @ByteCommander don't wait for me, edit it in!

Comment: Okay, I added what I thought is useful.