# !x not found - bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, history, bash-history

I made a simple bash script to run a range of commands in your history, but it's not working.

```
read -p "control + c to cancel"                                            
for i in $(seq $1 $2)                                                     
do                                                                         
  !${i}                                                                    
done
```

I run it like `runrange 5 10`, and it gives me `!5: command not found`. If I run `!5`, it works fine! How can I fix this?

Comment: Please do not do this. It is a staggeringly naive thing to do and I can almost guarantee that you will end up regretting it. Do not blindly run commands without seeing what they are!

Answer (score 1):

Bash performs history expansion as the [first thing after reading a line](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) of input, so it happens before expanding variables. The `!$` in your expansion `!${i}` [is taken to refer to the last argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators) of the previous command as a special case syntax.

If you want to read (or execute) the commands saved in the history, you can use [`history -p`, or `fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#Bash-History-Builtins).

Apart from that, note that you can't access an interactive shell's history from an external script, and there are more straightforward ways to repeat commands inside a script.

Comment: How does `history -p work`? if I do `history -p 5` it just echo's `5`

Comment: Is there a way to disable editor confirmation for `fc`? I want it to just run the command.

Answer (score 0):

The script is being executed in a non-interactive (and of course non-login) session of `bash`; in any non-interactive shell session, history expansion is disabled by default.

You need to add at the top of your script (after shebang):

- `set -o history` to enable history
- `set -o histexpand` (or `set -H`) to enable `!` style history substitution

Remember the history of the non-interactive session by default, will be kept in memory and flushed once the session terminates, so even above two options would not solve your actual problem, the real problem being what command have you typed so far and what are you expecting to get on any non-interactive session?

To get the idea, add `history` just before the `for` loop.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it doesn't actually seem to work. Did you try it? Also, the history inside the script will only be the history of commands the script ran, not the OP's actual history.

Comment: @terdon Thats exactly what i said in the last two paragraphs.

Comment: Ah, so you did. Sorry. But have you gotten the `!` expansions to work in a script? I don't think that's actually possible.

Comment: @terdon ummmm...will look thoroughly :)

Comment: Would there be another way of doing this without the `!` expansion?

Comment: @lol No straight forward way...I would suggest you do avoid playing with history expansion blindly...

Comment: So there is no way to run a range of commands from history?

Comment: possibly http://askubuntu.com/questions/629846/use-the-bang-commands-e-g-of-bash-in-scripts-and-aliases?rq=1 could help